# Using <div contenteditable="true">text</div> show stars instead of symbols

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using such way of using password fields

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

and AngularJS.

I have my custom directive on this element.

How to force show by typing any symbol here to show *, in the same way when using `<input text='password'>`

Comment: what is the custom directive?

Comment: it doesn't affect the behavior, I mentioned about that to point that I have access to all internals of Angular to manipulate of this object on keydown event

Comment: Your custom directive _should_ affect the behavior. That's what you're asking to do. Use the `link` function of the directive to implement the behavior you want.

Comment: by default the component doesn't work like that, directive is there to implement it

Comment: That's exactly what I said.

Comment: the answer was helpful :)

Comment: you really need to show something.  What have you tried

Comment: I was able to do it, but it requires really a lot of effort and code to achieve it